# Trying to return users from Table Storage Query to get request

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-table-storage

I just started to work with Azure Table Storage, and I'm trying to return the records from the query but after I execute queryEntities(), result.entites does not save the records to a variable. So, at the end of the function when I return that variable it is undefined.

Here is my code

**db.service.ts**

```
const azure = require('azure-storage');
const tableSvc = azure.createTableService('***', '***');

async function getAllRecords() {
  const query = new azure.TableQuery();

  let users = [];
  tableSvc.queryEntities('users', query, null, function(error, result, response) {
    if (!error){
      // here it logs the users succesfully
      console.log(result.entries);
      users = result.entries;
    }
  });

  // here it logs the variable with its starting value as empty array
  console.log(users);

  return users;
}
```

Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
async function getAllRecords() {
  const query = new azure.TableQuery();

  let users = [];
  
  let func = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    tableSvc.queryEntities('users', query, null, function(error, result, response) {
      if (!error){
        // here it logs the users succesfully
        //console.log(result.entries);
        users = result.entries;
        resolve("success message");
      }
    })
  })
  
  func.then(() => {
    console.log(users);
  })
  return users;
}
```